# Regex pattern to match three different things

Tags: regex

I need help to create 4 regex patterns to match 4 different things in a block of text.

This is the block of text (the names are irrelevant):

```
[2013/8/27 - 20:44:3] AdmCmd: Damian Santos was fined $1000 by Scott Parker, reason: BH(8-27-2013)
[2013/8/29 - 21:56:49] AdmCmd: Jimmy Greiner was fined $304389 by Scott Parker, reason: LOL(8-29-2013)
[2013/8/29 - 22:4:54] AdmCmd: Jimmy Greiner has been jailed by Scott Parker, reason: LOL(8-29-2013)
[2013/8/29 - 22:5:38] AdmCmd: Jimmy Greiner has been released from prison by Scott Parker, reason: TS(8-29-2013)
[2013/8/29 - 22:42:55] AdmCmd: James McAdams has been released from prison by Damian Santos, reason: test(8-29-2013)
[2013/8/30 - 20:17:23] AdmCmd: James McAdams has been released from prison by Scott Parker, reason: TS(8-30-2013)
[2013/8/30 - 20:26:15] AdmCmd: James McAdams has been jailed by Jimmy Greiner, reason: Test(8-30-2013)
[2013/8/30 - 20:26:37] AdmCmd: James McAdams has been released from prison by Scott Parker, reason: Test(8-30-2013)
[2013/8/31 - 11:35:35] AdmCmd: Scott Parker was fined $5000 by Scott Parker, reason: BH(8-31-2013)
[2013/8/31 - 11:36:0] AdmCmd: Scott Parker was fined $5000 by Scott Parker, reason: BH(8-31-2013)
[2013/8/31 - 11:36:49] AdmCmd: Damian Santos was fined $5000 by Scott Parker, reason: UNRP driving(8-31-2013)
```

I need to match the names who were: **fined**, **released** or **jailed**. I got a pattern for this one already:

```
[A-Za-z ]+(?=was|has)
```

I need the name of the person who issued one of these actions (the names near the end of each sentence). I tried to get a pattern for it, but I can't exclude the "by" word:

```
(?=by)[A-Za-z ]+(?=,)
```

I didn't try a pattern for the **reason** (without the date) and the **date**, which are both located at the end. I need them cut clean via a nice pattern.

I would appreciate some help.

Thank you.

Comment: If you haven't tried them yet, why not try them now? You say you already got 2 working. The last two shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Which language/plarform for regex?

Comment: Usually you'd use a single regex to grab all of those instead of matching 4 times per line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exclude the "by" you need to use a positive lookbehind, so change your `(?=by)` to `(?<=by)`.

For the reason, you can use this same method, `(?<=reason:)` followed by the regex to match the BH or whatever codes are expected.

And last but not least, it shouldnt be hard for you to capture the date "between" the parenthesis at the end of the line. You seem to be on the right track you should have no problem finishing it up!

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to get a pattern for it, but I can't exclude the "by" word:

Use positive lookbehing instead of positive lookahead:

```
(?<=by )[A-Za-z ]+(?=,)
```

Working [**DEMO**](http://regexr.com?369if)